# Nonlinear constraint in cplex

Tags: cplex

I am implementing a version of the bin packing problem in cplex and I had to introduce the following constraint, where y and x are boolean decision variables:

forall(i in itens)
   sum(j in bins) y[i][j] * x[j] == 1;

The problem is that when I run the model cplex give me the following error: "cplex can't extract the expression y[i][j] * x[j].

Does anyone know how to run this properly?

Answer (score 0):

if x and y are boolean decision variables, then in order to say

> z==x*y

you may write

> z<=x;
>   z<=y;
>   z>=x+y-1;

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `y[i][j] * x[j] = 1`not `y[i][j] * x[j] == 1`